# DEM from overlap monocular images Pleiades

Tags: dem, photogrammetry, stereo-imagery

I am trying to create a DEM from 4 overlap monocular satellite images of different dates from Pleiades using [UP42.com](https://up42.com/). But I could find only information about stereo images processing.

Is it even possible to obtain DEM from several **monocular** satellite images or I need to use only **stereo**-images? The problem is that we could not find any for our AOI. 
What tools would you recommend to start with?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create a DEM from several monocular Pleiades images, as long as they come with an RPC model, i.e. the L1A product, not the one that has already been orthorectified. The results will likely be worse than with tasked stereo images, but depending on your use case, might be usable.

I would reccomend you start with an open source project like [s2p](https://github.com/centreborelli/s2p) or [CARS](https://github.com/CNES/cars)